# How to handle huge sparse matrices construction using Scipy?

Tags: scipy, data-mining, sparse-matrix, information-retrieval, pagerank

So, I am working on a Wikipedia dump to compute the pageranks of around 5,700,000 pages give or take.
The files are preprocessed and hence are not in XML.
They are taken from http://haselgrove.id.au/wikipedia.htm
and the format is:

```
from_page(1): to(12) to(13) to(14)..
from_page(2): to(21) to(22)..
.
.
.
from_page(5,700,000): to(xy) to(xz)
```

so on. So. basically it's a construction of a `[5,700,000*5,700,000]` matrix, which would just break my 4 gigs of RAM. Since, it is very-very Sparse, that makes it easier to store using `scipy.lil.sparse` or `scipy.dok.sparse`, now my issue is:

*How on earth do I go about converting the `.txt` file with the link information to a sparse matrix? Read it and compute it as a normal N*N matrix then convert it or what?* I have no idea.

Also, the links sometimes span across lines so what would be the correct way to handle that?
eg: a random line is like..

```
[
1: 2 3 5 64636 867
2:355 776 2342 676 232
3: 545 64646 234242 55455 141414 454545 43
4234 5545345 2423424545
4:454 6776
]
```

exactly like this: no commas & no delimiters.

Any information on sparse matrix construction and data handling across lines would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Scipy offers several implementations of sparse matrices. Each of them has its own advantages and disadvantages. You can find information about the matrix formats [here](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/sparse.html):

There are several ways to get to your desired sparse matrix. Computing the full NxN matrix and then converting is probably not possible, due high memory requirements (about 10^12 entries!).

In your case I would prepare your data to construct a [coo_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.coo_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.coo_matrix).

```
coo_matrix((data, (i, j)), [shape=(M, N)])

data[:] the entries of the matrix, in any order
i[:] the row indices of the matrix entries
j[:] the column indices of the matrix entries
```

You might also want to have a look at [lil_matrix](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy-0.14.0/reference/generated/scipy.sparse.lil_matrix.html#scipy.sparse.lil_matrix), which can be used to incrementally build your matrix.

Once you created the matrix you can then convert it to a better suited format for calculation, depending on your use case.

I do not recognize the data format, there might be parsers for it, there might not. Writing your own parser should not be very difficult, though. Each line containing a colon starts a new row, all indices after the colon and in consecutive lines without colons are the column entries for said row.

Comment: Is there a way to directly build an `lil_matrix` from a list of sparse rows (each row being a list of (column, value) pairs)? That seems like the obvious approach, but doesn't seem to be supported.